# HTML5 canvas and javascript move player with mouse movement

Tags: javascript, html, function, canvas, html5-canvas

okay so far i can move the player with the arrow keys but i have been trying to figure out how to move the player with mouse movements such as moving the mouse to the right will increase the players X position and moving the mouse to the left will decrease the X position but i'm struggling to achieve this!

how i made my player object

```
player = {
    x: width / 30,//player properties 
    y: height - 5,
    width: 16,
    height: 18,
    speed: 3,
    velX: 0,
    velY: 0,
    jumping: false,
    grounded: false

},
```

my control functions

```
 if (keys[38] || keys[32]) {
    // up arrow or space
    if (!player.jumping && player.grounded) {
        player.jumping = true;
        player.grounded = false;
        player.velY = -player.speed * 2;
        var audio = new Audio('jump.mp3');
        audio.play();
    }
}
if (keys[39]) {
//mouseControl = false;
    // right arrow
    if (player.velX < player.speed) {
        player.velX++;

if(count ==2)
 {
 count = 0;
 }
else {
 count++;
}
    }
}
     if (keys[37]) {
   //mouseControl = false;
    // left arrow
    if (player.velX > -player.speed) {
        player.velX--;
        if(count ==2)
  {
   count = 0;

}
 else {
 count++;
 }
    }
}

player.velX *= friction;
player.velY += gravity;

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.beginPath();

player.grounded = false;
}
```

how i'm getting the keys

```
 //if key is pressed down = true
 document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
 });
 //if key is not pressed = false
 document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
keys[e.keyCode] = false;
 });


 window.addEventListener("load", function () {
game_loop();
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you will want to do is add a `mousemove` event. And have two variables to store the `oldX` and `oldY` mouse positions, along with the `newX` and `newY` mouse positions. Then on each call to `mousemove` the `newX` and `newY` will be the current mouse position and `oldX` and `oldY` will be the mouse positions of the last call to `mousemove`. Finally you simply subtract `newX - oldX` to get the difference in your mouses X position (`diffX`). If it's positive you moved the mouse to the right, if it's negative you moved the mouse to the left. The same thing goes for `diffY`. Here is an example:

```
var oldX = 0, oldY = 0, newX, newY;

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) 
{ 
    // Get the current mouse position
    var cRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    newX = e.clientX - cRect.left;
    newY = e.clientY - cRect.top;

    // Subtract from the old mouse position
    var diffX = newX - oldX;     
    var diffY = newY - oldY;         

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    if(diffX > 0)
        player.x += player.speed; // If the mouse moved right, move right
    else
        player.x -= player.speed; // Otherwise move left.

    ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, 50, 50); // draw player

    // Now make the current mouse potion the old mouse position
    oldX = newX;
    oldY = newY
});
```

[**Here is a working fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/fyww02r7/)

Comment: omg can't thank you enough thanks for explaining it well and giving me the code i understand it now just to make the left mouse button make the player jump.

Comment: @user186 You just need to add an `click` event to the `canvas`. And place your jump code in there. [**Example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fyww02r7/1/).

Comment: @user186 Just another note, if this answer answered your question you can mark it as "accepted", the green arrow on the left.

Comment: i tried adding my jump code in and it didn't jump hmmm but it runs with no errors

Comment: @user186 Was the jumping working before with just the arrow keys?

Comment: yes it works with the arrow keys but not with mouse button also since you seam to be an expert! do you mind if i also ask another question i'm wondering how to make a start and end screen

Comment: @user186 I would recommend asking it as a separate question. For your jumping issue could you give me a fiddle of the current entire program? I may be able to find whats causing the problem.

Comment: i'm only allowed to ask so many questions a day add my skype british.brah